# How do i use html tags in mysqli result uses Prepared statements?

Tags: php, html, mysqli

I recently noticed about a hack known as (SQL Injection) . I used Prepared Statements to avoid these attacks. that's the code i'm using:

```html
<?php
    session_start();
    if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST"){
    include "inc/config.php";
    $stmt = $link->prepare("UPDATE crany_cranies SET crany_bio=?  WHERE crany_id=? ") ;
    $stmt->bind_param("si", $bio,  $id);
    
    $id= test_input($_REQUEST['id']) ;
    $bio= test_input($_POST["bio"]);
    $stmt->execute();
    
    $stmt->close();
    $link->close();
    }
    
    ?>

  <form action=editbio.php?id=<?php echo $_REQUEST[ 'id']; ?> method="post">
    <?php
    include "inc/config.php";
    $id= test_input($_REQUEST['id']);
    $sql = "SELECT crany_bio, crany_keeper FROM crany_cranies WHERE crany_id=$id";
    $result = $link->query($sql);
    
    if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
        // output data of each row
        while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    //first
    if($row["crany_keeper"] != $_SESSION["id"]){
    header("location: index.php");
    }
    else{
    echo "you can use HTML tags only<br>";
    echo "<textarea name='bio' style='width:530px; font-size:11px; resize:none' cols='50' rows='15'>";
    echo $row["crany_bio"];
    echo "</textarea>";
    echo "<br><input type='submit'>";
    }
      }
    } else {
        echo "Invalid id";
    }
    $link->close();
    
    function test_input($data) {
      $data = trim($data);
      $data = stripslashes($data);
      $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
      return $data;
    }
    
    ?>

  </form>
```

that's for editing biography and I've used Prepared Statements for first SQL code. and works fine. But I got a new Problem that doesn't format HTML tags. and outputs whatever we write on textarea

I used these HTML tags and was working well before I use Prepared Statements

```html
<h2 style="color: white">xX Ammo Xx</h2>
<img src="http://68.media.tumblr.com/262aa3340cb98888f837e3fd82a214bd/tumblr_inline_nwr25xwGEf1sgemal_250.png">
<br>
<img src="flag/electric.png">
<br>
<p onclick="hideit()" id="click">click here!</p>
<img src="https://i.imgur.com/BSlHmyz.png">
<br> By <a href="http://flightrising.com/main.php?p=lair&tab=userpage&id=361930">Beppers!</a>
<script>
  function hideit() {
    document.getElementById("click").style.display = "none";
  }
</script>
```

are there any codes to use to format tags? Thank you

Comment: What is the problem ? Just store it as string,  prepared statements do prevent SQL injection attacks so you are OK

Comment: `htmlspecialchars` turns characters like `<` into `&gt;` It's perfectly safe to store HTML in the DB so you can remove the `htmlspecialchars` call and then it would be saved as actual HTML. You might want to look at `strip_tags` instead to remove tags you subsequently don't want to render. It's also up to you whether you do your clean up before inserts or during render.

Comment: @MorganFreeFarm problem is here that doesn't format html tags and outputs whatever i've written

Comment: So you input <b>test</p> and outputs is `test` ? without tags ?

Comment: @MorganFreeFarm  no, that outputs <b>test</p>

Comment: So it outputs <b>test</p>, but you want to otputs `test` ?

Comment: @MorganFreeFarm yes

Comment: Can you dump `var_dump(get_magic_quotes_gpc());` true or false, somewhere in your script ?

Comment: @MorganFreeFarm it's false

Answer (score 0):

To allow a user to enter HTML the **best practice** is to store the data they entered in the database as-is and encode it, say with *htmlspecialchars*, within the textarea.  When you want to display it as HTML, you display it as-is without the *htmlspecialchars* encoding. You are creating a new security flaw known as an **XSS injection** vulnerability though since nothing in your code will stop them from entering javascript.

```html
<?php
    session_start();
    if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST"){
    include "inc/config.php";
    $stmt = $link->prepare("UPDATE crany_cranies SET crany_bio=?  WHERE crany_id=? ") ;
    $stmt->bind_param("si", $bio,  $id);
    
    $id= test_input($_REQUEST['id']) ;
    $bio= test_input($_POST["bio"]);
    $stmt->execute();
    
    $stmt->close();
    $link->close();
    }
    
    ?>

  <form action=editbio.php?id=<?php echo $_REQUEST[ 'id']; ?> method="post">
    <?php
    include "inc/config.php";
    $id= test_input($_REQUEST['id']);
    $sql = "SELECT crany_bio, crany_keeper FROM crany_cranies WHERE crany_id=$id";
    $result = $link->query($sql);
    
    if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
        // output data of each row
        while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    //first
    if($row["crany_keeper"] != $_SESSION["id"]){
    header("location: index.php");
    }
    else{
    echo "you can use HTML tags only<br>";
    echo "<textarea name='bio' style='width:530px; font-size:11px; resize:none' cols='50' rows='15'>";
    echo htmlspecialchars($row["crany_bio"]);
    //     ^^^   HTML Tags will break the textarea if not encoded
    echo "</textarea>";
    echo "<br><input type='submit'>";
    }
      }
    } else {
        echo "Invalid id";
    }
    $link->close();
    
    function test_input($data) {
      // $data = trim($data);
      // $data = stripslashes($data);
      // $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
      //  ^^^ Don't encode data before it goes into the database
      return $data;
    }
    
    ?>

  </form>
```

Without seeing your previous code I can't imagine how it worked beforehand.

Comment: i've figured it out before. but thank you. altough i had done similar to your codes but diidn't worked